# Java Drawing Graphics

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am making a game in Java and I have a canvas class, which has the game tick, and I draw the images on the canvas using

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // draw stuff here
}
```

I want to move all the drawing functions to my Engine class.
I have this method in my Engine:

```
@Override
public void render(Graphics scene) {
 // draw stuff here
}
```

In my Canvas I didn't have to call the paint method, but in the Engine I would have to call the render method, but since it takes as an argument Graphics scene, I am kind of at a loss.  How would I be able to draw components from my Engine class(using the render method) and not from the Canvas class.

The engine class does not extend any JComponent, but it does initialize the Canvas object

Comment: you can call render from paint can't you ...?

Comment: @pinkpanther No, because my class doesn't actually extend any component, but it initializes the Canvas object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am making a game in Java and I have a canvas class, which has the
> game tick, and I draw the images on the canvas using

note

> public void paint(Graphics g) { for awt.Canvas, awt.Panel
>
> public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { for swing.JComponent, swing.JPanel

- any painting could be done only for J/Component, good practicies couldn't be move this methods outside of J/Component declarations

> I want to move all the drawing functions to my Engine class. I have
> this method in my Engine:

- is good idea to prepare all Object before paint/paintComponent is executed,
- there to put all Objects to the array
- inside paint/paintComponent only loop inside arrays of prepared Obects, invoked from Swing Timer, Mouse/Key events
- all events for paiting, to AWT/Swing GUI must be done on Event Dispatch Thread
- for todays GUI to use Swing JComponent, JPanel and override paintComponent
- a few very good code examples are here, tagged by paintComponent

Comment: ok :) so basically in my engine class I would put all objects that need to be drawn (player, ai, etc..) into an array. And in the canvas class I would just loop through the array drawing  each object. I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that there is no way for Engine to know that `paint(g)` is called, since the call is run on the canvas. So you will most likely need to modify `Canvas.paint` so that it calls the `Engine`. It's possible there is some funky listener you could add to `Canvas` but I think that's probably more complicated than you need.

One way that would work would be to pass an instance of `Engine` to the `Canvas` on construction:

```
public class Engine {
    private Canvas canvas;
    public Engine() {
        Canvas = new Canvas(this);
    }
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private Engine engine;
    public Canvas(Engine engine) {
         this.engine = engine;
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          engine.render(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this method would work, I should add that, as the other answer indicates, it's a better idea to separate the graphics and the backend.